# Symfony2 and php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle failed messages

Tags: php, api, symfony, rabbitmq

Is it possible to detect if message queue fails with fatal error on client code and upon detection delete message causing fatal error?

I'm working with big data import from third party api and using rabbitmq to process all the data from api. There are more than 10 queues and some of them sometimes get stuck piling up messages because it gets shut down due to fatal error in client code. Is there a way to handle this through RabbitMQ api without touching the client code?

I read through documentation but can't find a way to do this.

Comment: You need to wrap the pieces of codes where Rabbitmq is called, with `try->catch` snippets. This way you can protect it from crashing.

Comment: @Confidence i'm calling the rabbitmq when i need to publish messages to queue, but errors surface when messages are already published and executed by RabbitMQ

Comment: yes exactly.....wrap this handling with try -> catch, so your workers do not keep crashing

Comment: Simple as that:) Thank you so much!